# javaScript: can someone explain this

Tags: javascript, json

What does this mean?

```
var settings = {
    "column-1" : ["block-1"], 
    "column-2" : ["block-2"]
};
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why this has -4 votes? I looked through the revision history and I don't see anything ever in this question that made it worth so many downvotes.

Comment: @BoltClock, elitism, probably :|

Comment: @Rob: Now it just looks like someone is butthurt that we are editing his stuff.

Comment: @Bibhaw: According to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."

Comment: @BoltClock : I'm surprised to see the  wired comment of some users. I have nothing to say but the way i got response from some techie it make me not to put any question over here. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will create a new object and store it in the `settings variable`.

The object is created by an **Object literal** and consist out of two **propertys** (`column-1` and `column-2`) which are both assigned an **Array** with a single **String** value.

Answer (score 10):

It means one should [likely] read a tutorial/book on JavaScript before asking questions like this on SO ;-) (Explaining what "it means" will likely have not much "practical meaning" by itself.)

Like [Eloquent JavaScript: A Modern Introduction to Programming](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)

I believe the exact construct/term that is being sought is "object literals" -- `{...}` is for objects and `[...]` is for arrays.

Happy coding.

Comment: @Bibhaw: Hence getting negative reactions from the community. **Learn first ask later** (*stupid questions*).

Answer (score 3):

It defines an object containing two properties (column-1 and column-2) which both contain arrays which both contain a single value (block-1 an block-2).

Due to the `-` in the property name it will be impossible to access them using the `object.property` syntax so you'll have to use the array syntax: `object['property']`

Answer (score 3):

Initialized a variable named `settings` and assigned the value `{"column-1": ["block"], "column-2": ["block-2"]}`, which is an object, to the settings.